# Websql read doesn't work on ionic based app?

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, web-sql, ionic-framework

```js
.controller("testCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.test = "123";
  var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
  //create db
  var db = openDatabase("Products", "", "Product Cart", dbSize, function() {
    console.log('db successfully opened or created');
  });
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, productName TEXT, price TEXT , imgPath TEXT, isCart BIT)");
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO product(productName, price, imgPath, isCart) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",['testP','100','imgp','1']);
         $scope.testClick = function(){
            tx.executeSql('SELECT productName FROM product', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    console.log(results.rows.item(i).text);
                }
        });
  }

    });

 
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="testCtrl">
        {{test}}
        <button class="button" ng-click="testClick()">click</button>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here i have attached my controller code and html code. When i have click the button i got this error **"Failed to execute 'executeSql' on 'SQLTransaction': SQL execution is disallowed."**. How can i fix this? thank you

Comment: create a new tx inside $scope.testClick   function. Because inde the testClick scope the tx is already disposed.

Comment: Thank you @Dilhan Jayathilake